# Swashbuckle OAuth2 Authorization with Client Credentials Flow

Tags: javascript, c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I use Swashbuckle to documentation of WebAPI controllers. Also I use OAuth2 with Client Credentials Flow. So to authorize I need to pass  `client_id` and `client_secret`.

I have following code:

```
config.EnableSwagger(c => {
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "My API");
    c.OAuth2("oauth2")
        .Flow("application")
        .TokenUrl("/oauth2/token");
    c.OperationFilter<AssignOAuthSecurityRequirements>();
})
.EnableSwaggerUi(c => {
    c.EnableOAuth2Support(clientId: "clientIdValue", clientSecret:"clientSecretValue", "", "");
    c.CustomAsset("index", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "WebAPI.Swagger.UI.index.html");
});
```

Authorization works fine but my `client_id` and `client_secret` values are hardcoded(clientIdValue, clientSecretValue). How can I add possibility to input that values by user in this dialog? Can anyone help me?

[image]

Please let me know if I need to post  code of `AssignOAuthSecurityRequirements` too. Thanks all in advance

Comment: did you resolve this one? i am looking a solution for the same question.

Comment: Ditto, I am also curious how I can obtain a dialog where a consumer may enter their client_id and client_secret to authenticate.  Is this possible in swagger?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what went wrong in your code, maybe the lack of scope definitions.

I've done it successfully with ASP.NET Core and the current version of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)

The client credentials flow is referred to as "application" so, in your Startup.cs file, you need to configure Swagger as follows:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {

            //other configs...

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme {
                Type = "oauth2",
                Flow = "application",
                TokenUrl = "<token_endpoint_url>",
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "first-scope", "First scope description" },
                    { "second-scope", "Second scope description" }
                    //define as many scopes as you want...
                }
            });
        });
```

The TokenUrl parameter must point to a valid OAuth 2.0 compliant Token endpoint (checkout http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html for a sample on how the endpoint should behave/look like). Both absolute and relative URLs worked in my tests.

After that, the authorization dialog should look like bellow:

[image: Authorize popup]

- Please note, that you need to select at least one scope before the authorize button actually submits anything (the oauth component should be changed to add a disclaimer IMHO).

No additional configuration was required in the SwaggerUI section.

Comment: Note that the current flow name for the client credentials flow is now "clientCredentials" see: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/